# How to setup Facebook Timeline Cover Photo website . is it easy for a basic web developer?

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

I have seen many website build with wordpress and they have  facebook timeline cover photos auto upload.

anyone please help me?

sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

it isn't difficult at all... you can get the cover url for a page/user using the facebook graph api.

ie: querying http://graph.facebook.com/cocacola?fields=cover will return the cover image properties for the cocacola fan page, simply use the 'source' field as your image src. *(this is a 720px wide cover image)*

as your using wordpress you could make a widget out of it, or hard code it in the template (eww..).

*(on another note - you may want to additionally implement some form of caching for the facebook grapi api result so you don't continuously query facebook on every page load for the cover url.)*

Answer (score 0):

Majid Khan,
try [this](http://timelinecoverphotos.in/facebookcovers/), facebook image uploader (for timeline and more.....)

work fine on wordpress and more....but it is not free

Answer (score 0):

Timeline is the [New Facebook Timeline covers](http://www.timelinecovershelp.com/) profile. Tell your life story through photos, friendships and personal milestones like graduating or traveling to new places.