# facebook cover as div background

Tags: jquery, facebook, cover

Well s the title says I just want to use the facebook cover as background for some div in a website, so whenever I update my cover it automatically updates the image on the site.

in another thread somebody said that was really easy, but I donut have the skills in jQuery to do the code can someone help me with this?

The mentioned thread: [How to setup Facebook Timeline Cover Photo website . is it easy for a basic web developer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10675632/how-to-setup-facebook-timeline-cover-photo-website-is-it-easy-for-a-basic-web)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace MY_FACEBOOK_URL_NAME with whatever yours is or your graph user id number.

```
$.getJSON('http://graph.facebook.com/MY_FACEBOOK_URL_NAME?fields=cover&callback=?', function(data){
    $('#myDiv').css('background-image','url(' + data.cover.source + ')');
});
```